# Import Symfony2 Bundle in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I didn't find country list in Laravel 4 so I searches one and I find [umpirsky/country-list](https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list)

It seems to be used with [NoiselabsCountryBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/NoiselabsCountryBundle) which is a bundle for Symfony2

Is there an easy way to use this bundle with Laravel ?
And generally, is there an easy way to use Symfony2 bundles with Laravel ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the actual repo itself, you don't need the bundle.

As the country list library has a composer.json in its repository, you can install it to your app by adding "umpirsky/country-list" to your list of dependencies in your `composer.json` file, run `composer update` and the classes from the package will be available automatically thanks to autoloading.

Comment: I add it but I don't know how to use it.
That's why I added NoiselabsCountryBundle

Comment: Ah, I just looked at it. It appears it only has code for recreating the lists. Meh.

Comment: Yes it contains all generated files but no method to call them.
NoiselabsCountryBundle has the methods but I can't call it. Maybe it needs a ServiceProvider file ?

Comment: Yeah, I might create a package for Laravel during the weekend, if you don't. It would give you a simple facade for accessing the data.